# appcelerator titanium - no 'new titanium mobile project' menu option after fresh install

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have just installed the very latest stable titanium for windows 8 (x64), android sdk etc etc.   All have installed ok and titanium studio's checks show android as being installed correctly.

The problem is that under the 'file / new' menu, I don't have the "titanium mobile project" as an option.  Watching and reading various online resources about getting started with Titanium for mobile, I see that this is what I need to click on.

Can anyone assist in checking any plugins I should verify I have installed within the ide or anything else that may appear to be relevant ?

To confirm; I get 3 project types currently.  These are

Titanium Project...
Titanium Module Project...
Project...

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/147168/cant-find-mobile-project-in-new-tab

Comment: thanks so much! such an easy answer for once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titanium project is the new titanium mobile project according to another forum since the titanium desktop option is no longer included.

Comment: Do you have a source you can link to? It would be more helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Link by Muhammad Zeeshan in first comment to the question.